# playing videos stored as string from database using html5 c# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i have a code that uploads my videos on a folder and its file path is stored in the sql server database.

i dont know how to play the video on another seperate page

any help or code would be much appreciated.

the following is my upload code

```
protected void btnInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string name = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength == 0)
        { 
            Label1.Text = "Cannot upload zero length file";
        }

        if (ext == ".wmv" || ext == ".flv" || ext == ".avi" || ext == ".mp4" || ext == ".3GP" || ext == ".wma")
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string tme = dt.ToLongTimeString();
            string[] t = tme.Split(':');

            string y = "";
            foreach (string x in t)
            {
                y += x;
            }

            string aa = y + "_" + name;

            string Video = FileUpload1.FileName;
            string folder_path = Server.MapPath("~\\Video\\");
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(folder_path + Video);

            string loc = aa;
            //Session["location1"] = loc;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=137.158.107.212;Initial Catalog=VideoDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=G0;Password=*********.");
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("videoupload2", sqlconn);
            sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@video_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = videonametextbox.Text;
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@video_loc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = loc;
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@video_language", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = languagetextbox.Text;

            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();

            Label2.Text = "Video Song uploaded Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "please choose video file";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the path of your videos to a free Video player such as [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/). (Free only for non-commercial sites).

**Step 1**: To include file flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js in the web page you place the following tag in the HEAD section of your web page:

```
<script src="path/to/the/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
```

To place the link to your video file in the web page, the simplest way is to use the following A tag on your web page. The video will automatically play there:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/myVideo.flv"
   style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;"
   id="player">
</a>
```

**Step 3**: Finally, to load the player on the A tag just described, you place the following script in your page, following the A tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  flowplayer("player", "path/to/the/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
</script>
```

Comment: I guess he is going to need some encoding of the uploaded videos to use FlowPlayer

Comment: hi, ok i understand how to load the tag for the flow player, but how do i call a specific video from the database to play?

Comment: I assume you save the full path of the video in the filesystem into the database right? You can use this path.

Comment: so do i type below flowplayer value = "~/Video/"

Comment: Yes, and append the filename + file extension

Comment: could you please please show me the code for that?? im sstill quite confused as to what to do